# Сделать автотабуляцию кода

Tags: yaml, yml

Плагин не воспринимает конфиг как рабочий, я так понимаю ему не нравится то что нет отступов....
Как сделать автокорректирование кода?)

```
quests:
1:
type: kill-mob
variable: zombie
name: 'Неделя 2 - Выживший Апокалипсиса'
required-progress: 200
points: 100
item:
material: stone_sword:0
name: '&d&lКВЕСТ: &fУбийца Зомби'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для завершения этого квеста, вы должны'
- '&8 » &7убить 200 зомби.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Battlepass: &fБесплатно'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
2:
type: regenerate
variable: MAGIC
name: 'Неделя 2 - Любовь к Себе'
required-progress: 20
points: 100
item:
material: golden_apple
name: '&d&lКВЕСТ: &fЛюбовь к Себе'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для завершения этого квеста, вы должны'
- '&8 » &7использовать 20 зелий для восстановления сердец.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Battlepass: &fБесплатно'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
3:
type: ride-mob
variable: pig
name: 'Неделя 2 - Верхом на Беконе'
required-progress: 1
points: 100
item:
material: pig_spawn_egg
name: '&d&lКВЕСТ: &fВерхом на Беконе'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для завершения этого квеста, вы должны'
- '&8 » &7поехать на свинье один раз.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Battlepass: &fБесплатно'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
4:
type: smelt
variable: glass
name: 'Неделя 2 - Установщик стекла'
required-progress: 320
points: 100
item:
material: glass
name: '&d&lЗАДАНИЕ: &fУстановщик стекла'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Чтобы выполнить это задание, вы должны'
- '&8 » &7исплавить 5 стопок песка.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fБесплатный'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
5:
type: enchant-all
variable:
root: MENDING
level: 1
name: 'Неделя 2 - Волшебник'
required-progress: 1
points: 100
item:
material: enchanting_table
name: '&d&lЗАДАНИЕ: &fВолшебник'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Чтобы выполнить это задание, вы должны'
- '&8 » &7зачаровать железную кирку на восстановление.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fБесплатный'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
6:
type: item-break
variable: golden_pickaxe
name: 'Неделя 2 - Нужна модернизация'
required-progress: 1
points: 100
item:
material: golden_pickaxe
name: '&d&lЗАДАНИЕ: &fНужна модернизация'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Чтобы выполнить это задание, вы должны'
- '&8 » &7сломать золотую кирку при добыче руды.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fБесплатный'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
7:
type: consume
variable: cooked_beef
name: 'Неделя 2 - Пир'
required-progress: 45
points: 100
item:
material: cooked_beef
name: '&d&lЗАДАНИЕ: &fПир'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для выполнения этого задания необходимо'
- '&8 » &7съесть/использовать 45 кусков стейка.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fБесплатный'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
8:
type: fish
variable: none
name: 'Неделя 2 - Поймай что-нибудь'
required-progress: 12
points: 100
item:
material: book
name: '&d&lЗАДАНИЕ: &fПоймай что-нибудь'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для выполнения этого задания необходимо'
- '&8 » &7поймать 12 предметов/рыбы из пруда.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f100x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fБесплатный'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
9:
type: execute-command
variable: /home
name: 'Неделя 2 - Нет ничего лучше, чем дом'
required-progress: 5
points: 50
exclusive: premium
item:
material: book
name: '&d&lЗАДАНИЕ: &fНет ничего лучше, чем дом'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для выполнения этого задания необходимо'
- '&8 » &7ввести команду "/home" в чате.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f50x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fПремиум'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
10:
type: milk
variable: none
name: 'Неделя 2 - Работа на Ферме'
required-progress: 20
points: 50
exclusive: premium
item:
material: book
name: '&d&lКВЕСТ: &fРабота на Ферме'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для выполнения этого задания вы должны'
- '&8 » &7доить 20 коров.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f50x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fПремиум'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
11:
type: sneak
variable: none
name: 'Неделя 2 - Пресмыкающиеся'
required-progress: 200
points: 50
exclusive: premium
item:
material: book
name: '&d&lКВЕСТ: &fПресмыкающиеся'
lore:
- '&8 » &7Для выполнения этого задания вы должны'
- '&8 » &7пройти на пересечении 200 блоков.'
- ''
- '&d&lИНФОРМАЦИЯ'
- '&8 » &7Очки: &f50x'
- '&8 » &7Боевой пропуск: &fПремиум'
- '&8 » &7Прогресс: &a%total_progress%&8/&c%required_progress%'
```

Answer (score 1):

В языке разметки YAML используются [отступы из пробелов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9) для обозначения структуры, подобно как в языке программирования Python.

Автоматические инструменты не смогут за вас понять, какая была структура у документа.

Например, сравните эти два YAML-документа:

```yaml
---
a:
  b:
  c:
```

```yaml
---
a:
  b:
    c:
```

Оба документа являются [валидными](https://www.yamllint.com) YAML-файлами.

Comment: А как можно сделать, если есть ориг. файлы? Это изменённые файлы нейронкой чатгпт.

Comment: Переводил чатгпт, а табуляцию сделать не в состоянии

Comment: Конфиг yml можно автоматически отформатировать с помощью различных онлайн-инструментов. Один из таких инструментов - это онлайн-конвертер YAML, который автоматически форматирует конфигурационный файл YAML и добавляет отступы и пробелы.

Comment: @Ikdan, если вам помог какой-то онлайн-инструмент, то напишите об этом ответ. Мой ответ заключается в том, что такого инструмента не может существовать, а если он в каком-то виде существует, то будет работать некорректно на некоторых входных данных.

Comment: ChatGPT помог, сделал автотабуляцию